# What is the logic behind this implementation of _.shuffle?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Can anyone step me through how this implementation variation works?

I'm a bit confused as to how we ensure that the random number generated (aka the index we're trying to access) by *var rand* is unique in order to ensure we're shuffling the given array.

Eg. given [1,2,3,4] we return [3,4,2,1] and not [3,3,4,4] because the random number generated happened to repeat the index of 2 and 3?

```html
  _.shuffle = function(array) {
    var newArr = array.slice();
      for (var i=array.length-1; i>0; i--) {
       var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * i);
       var temp = newArr[rand];
       newArr[rand] = newArr[i];
       newArr[i] = temp;
       }
   return newArr;
  };
```

Comment: Why do it needs to be _unique_?

Comment: I just clarified my question a bit, but I was under the impression we needed to generate unique indices in order to really qualify to 'shuffle'? @Satpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ran` doesn't need to be unique.

For each iteration of the `for` loop, the shuffling algorithm will swap two items in the array.

As such, it is fine if `ran` is not unique as we can re-swap two items multiples times without it causing issues.

Also, note that the array is mutated. So for each iteration of the loop, we operate on the latest state of the array. This means we're not creating duplicates if we swap the same index multiple times.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much Simon. Especially your last comment about array being mutated - that definitely cleared things up. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's called Fisher-Yates shuffle. Wikipedia has a rather elaborate article about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 0):

Read the [annotated version of the source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-39):

> Shuffle a collection, using the modern version of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

And no, `rand` is not generated unique, it can be the same number in different iterations. But by the design of the algorithm, it always points at a non-shuffled element (in the range `[0, i]`).

Answer (score 0):

It is a good example of a bad implementation of handling random values.

With `Math.round`, you get results who are not really equal distributed, that means at start and end of the whole range, you get only half of the values, you need to have.

```
var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * i);
//              ^^^^^
```

```js
var _ = {},
    i,
    array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
    count = { };

_.shuffle = function (array) {
    var newArr = array.slice();
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * i);
        var temp = newArr[rand];
        newArr[rand] = newArr[i];
        newArr[i] = temp;
    }
    return newArr;
};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    count[a] = count[a] || [];
});
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    _.shuffle(array).forEach(function (a, i) {
        count[a][i] = (count[a][i] || 0) + 1;
    });
}
console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Example with distribution with

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
//              ^^^^^                    ^^^
```

```js
var _ = {},
    i,
    array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
    count = { };

_.shuffle = function (array) {
    var newArr = array.slice();
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = newArr[rand];
        newArr[rand] = newArr[i];
        newArr[i] = temp;
    }
    return newArr;
};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    count[a] = count[a] || [];
});
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    _.shuffle(array).forEach(function (a, i) {
        count[a][i] = (count[a][i] || 0) + 1;
    });
}
console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```